# "Non-zero exit status" error message when installing ggplot2 in RStudio

Tags: r, ggplot2, package

I have previously used ggplot2, in fact I was using the package as this problem arose.

I updated all of my packages, and found that I could no longer access basic packages (ggplot2, tidyvers, dplyr ect). When I try to install packages via  `install.packages("ggplot2")`, I receive the error message attached below.

I then proceed to use the library with `library(ggplot2)`, and the error message, `"there is no package called ‘ggplot2’"` is deployed. I am using R version 3.5.1 and R studio 1.1.423. I am using Mac version 10.12.6 (macOS Sierra), using an outdated version for other reasons. I am writing my current code in RStudio. Can anyone decipher what is going on with my code?

[image: ggplot2 install error message]

Comment: You're missing the MacOS C++ compiler (notice the error `...-clang++: command not found`) and need to install Xcode or the Xcode Command Line Tools. I'm also curious why you're installing R through anaconda rather than using the MacOS-native R.

Comment: Instructions related to the issue raised by @MauritsEvers : https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200486498-Package-Development-Prerequisites

Comment: @MauritsEvers Thank you, I updated my command line tools but am still receiving this error. As far as anaconda, I am a student with beginner programming knowledge. We were taught to install R through anaconda, to standardize between Mac and PC. See error message below.

Comment: @ks5280 Odd, the error suggests that it cannot find `clang` (the MacOS C compiler). Have you tried restarting the OS? Check that `clang` is installed and can be located. For example, open a terminal and type `which clang`. This should return the location of the `clang` executable.

Answer (score 0):

Error message seen when command line tools were updated

[Error Message 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOxw9.png)